# docker generates "fatal: write error: Read-only file" using git clone

Tags: docker

Question How do I avoid "fatal: write error: Read-only file" problem when using git clone.

Error occurs inside a docker instance
docker run -it imagename /bin/bash

RESULTS:

```
root@imagename:~/# git clone user@address:repo dir_name
Cloning into 'dir_name'...
remote: Counting objects: 79344, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (30878/30878), done.
fatal: write error: Read-only file system76 GiB | 5.31 MiB/s
fatal: index-pack failed
```

What is the correct magic invocation to do this successfully ?

Comment: Did you try running docker with '--privileged=true' option?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when the docker storage space were full (limit in 20GB).

If you pulled too much images or run too many containers, you will see this error.

Clean some images or container will help.